# json encode using codeigniter framework

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

here i m doing a json_encode

```
  public function get_posts_for_category($user_id,$category_id,$page)
{
    $cat_id = $this->ApiModel->get_category_id($category_id);
    $total_row = $this->ApiModel->get_category_posts_count($cat_id->category);
    $per_page = 2;
    $total_pages = $total_row / $per_page;
    $posts = $this->ApiModel->get_category_posts($cat_id->category,$per_page,$page);
    $data = array();
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
        $fav = $this->ApiModel->get_favourite($user_id,$post->pid);
        if($fav == 1)
        {
            $status = 'true';
        } 
        else 
        {
            $status = 'false'; 
        }
        $array = array('pid' => $post->pid, 'uid' => $post->uid, 'title' => $post->title, 'slug' => $post->slug, 'content' => $post->content, 'image' => $post->image, 'time_stamp' => $post->time_stamp);
        $data[] = array('page' => $page, 'posts' => $array, 'is_favorite' => $status);
    }
    echo strip_tags(json_encode($data));
}
```

the output i m getting from the above code is

[image]

But i want some thing like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    public function get_posts_for_category($user_id,$category_id,$page)
    {
    $cat_id = $this->ApiModel->get_category_id($category_id);
    $total_row = $this->ApiModel->get_category_posts_count($cat_id->category);
    $per_page = 2;
    $total_pages = $total_row / $per_page;
    $posts = $this->ApiModel->get_category_posts($cat_id->category,$per_page,$page);
    $data = array();
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
    $fav = $this->ApiModel->get_favourite($user_id,$post->pid);
    if($fav == 1)
    {
    $status = 'true';
    } 
    else 
    {
    $status = 'false'; 
    }
    $array = array('pid' => $post->pid, 'uid' => $post->uid, 'title' => $post->title, 'slug' => $post->slug, 'content' => $post->content, 'image' => $post->image, 'time_stamp' => $post->time_stamp, 'is_favorite' => $status);
    $data[] = array('page' => $page, 'posts' => $array, 'total_posts' => count($posts), 'total_pages' => $total_pages);
    }
    echo strip_tags(json_encode($data));
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $return = array(
        'page' => $page,
        'total_posts' => $total_row,
        'total_page' => $total_pages,
    );
    $data = [];
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
        $fav = $this->ApiModel->get_favourite($user_id, $post->pid);
        if($fav == 1)
        {
            $status = 'true';
        }
        else
        {
            $status = 'false';
        }
        $array = array('pid' => $post->pid, 'uid' => $post->uid, 'title' => $post->title, 'slug' => $post->slug, 'content' => $post->content, 'image' => $post->image, 'time_stamp' => $post->time_stamp, 'is_favorite' => $status);
        $data[] = $array;
    }
    $return['posts'] = $data;
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($return));
```

just replace this code with your `foreach` & `echo` statement.

You never should use `strip_tags` in conjunction with `json_encode` because you are already encoding the data it's receivers choice to do whatever he wants also in this process you might break the encoding.

Also you should use `CI` output library to send response you must not echo anything from your controller. see here https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html for more details

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the numeric values to be output as such, (instead of strings) you may wish to try:

```
json_encode($return, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

To format the outputted JSON nicely (indentation etc) use:

```
json_encode($return, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

You can use various combinations of the above as per [json_encode's options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

As for the boolean values (instead of "true" and "false" returned as strings), you'll need to cast them as boolean types first:

```
$status = (bool) true;
```